# Using Excel to generate SQL - problem handling date field

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel file filled with data my customer wants placed into a database. I've generated a column along the left of the data that looks like this (obviously changed the field names for here):

```
="INSERT INTO TBL_CUSTOMER
                      (FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, CUSTOMER_DATE_REGISTERED)
VALUES     ('"&D2&"','"&E2&"','"&F2&"','"&G2&"','"&H2&"','"&I2&"','"&J2&"','"&K2&"','"&L2&"','"&M2&"','"&N2&"','"&O2&"','"&P2&"','"&Q2&"','"&R2&"','"&S2&"','"&T2&"','"&U2&"','"&V2&"','"&W2&"','"&X2&"','"&Y2&"','"&Z2&"','"&AA2&"','"&AB2&"','"&AC2&"')"
```

Everything works perfectly but the problem is that the last item (Cell AC2) is a date in the format 25/12/2010  08:45:45. Excel is reading this as 40537.3651041667.

Any idea how to make it appear correctly?

Hope you guys can help!

Edit: Nomatted what i set the cell format to for AC2 I still get that random number pulled into the query

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the TEXT() function...

```
TEXT(AC2, "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss")
```

This returns a string from a value in the specified format

```
="INSERT INTO TBL_CUSTOMER
                      (FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, FIELD, 
                      FIELD, FIELD, CUSTOMER_DATE_REGISTERED)
VALUES 
    ('"&D2&"','"&E2&"','"&F2&"','"&G2&"','"&H2&"','"&I2&"','"&J2&"','"&K2&"','"&L2&"','"&M2&"','"&N2&"','"&O2&"','"&P2&"','"&Q2&"','"&R2&"','"&S2&"','"&T2&"','"&U2&"','"&V2&"','"&W2&"','"&X2&"','"&Y2&"','"&Z2&"','"&AA2&"','"&AB2&"',
'"&TEXT(AC2, "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss")&"')"
```

Comment: Grate solution. Reduced 70% of manual work. Same can be applied to Time columns as well,

Answer (score 0):

Use the TEXT function with a region-agnostic format

```
TEXT(AC2, "yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss")
```

or

```
TEXT(AC2, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for a while. Use semicolon instead of coma.

(Office16)

**TEXT(AC2; "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss")**

Instead of

TEXT(AC2, "dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss")